# Selection of records that has dependecies between them

Tags: sql, t-sql, entity-framework-migrations

I need to update a selection from a table with a boolean flag. Below is an example that shows what i whant.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers2](
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RankID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AnswerTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [OnTop] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (9, 1, 1, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 1, 1, CAST(0x0000A3A400C5C100 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 2, 2, CAST(0x0000A3A400D63BC0 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 3, 3, CAST(0x0000A3A400CDFE60 AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 4, 4, CAST(0x0000A3A400E6B680 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 5, 5, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (10, 6, 6, CAST(0x0000A3A400F73140 AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (11, 1, 1, CAST(0x0000A3A400D63BC0 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (11, 2, 2, CAST(0x0000A3A400C5C100 AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (11, 3, 3, CAST(0x0000A3A400CDFE60 AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (11, 4, 4, CAST(0x0000A3A400E6B680 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (11, 5, 5, CAST(0x0000A3A400EEF3E0 AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Answers2] ([GroupID], [CompanyID], [RankID], [AnswerTime], [OnTop]) VALUES (12, 1, 1, CAST(0x0000A3A400F73140 AS DateTime), 1)
```

The logic as follows .
A question is send to one or more companys at a time. If a company have a highest rank it get the OnTop bit set. When they answer the next following company(according to rank and groupID) that has NOT answered will get the OnTop bit set to true. If a company with OnTop flag never answers no company that follows(according to rank and groupid) will get it.

I could solve this with cursors but this is to be used in an EF-migration so it has to be one statment that updates all the old records with the new OnTop flag.
 I tried to make a inner join on itself and look if time and rank was lower but that doesnt count for the entire tree of the group above the current post. 
Any ideas or codesuggestions would be very appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with recursive relations in SQL Server the best way is to use [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). They can be used to recursively traverse trees.

Using cursors is an option too. As far as I know, there is no limit on the length/size/complexity of SQL statements you can call during a migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a migration for a specific database you can before hand check the maximum number of levels in your table and make that many self joins.